# Override equals in Python but still have reference equality check

Tags: python, equals, overriding

I have overridden equals in Python but I would still like to do a reference equality check.  In Java, this is the difference between == and equals.  Does Python have a similar ability?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can test if two objects are the same object with `is`:

```
>>> a = 12
>>> a is a
True
```

Comment: You might want to include an example where two variables reference equal objects that aren't the same. Something like http://ideone.com/r3uFUz

Answer (score 2):

You can use the builtin [id](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#id) for this purpose

```
>>> A=[1]
>>> B=A
>>> id(A) == id(B)
True
>>> A == B
True
>>> C = [1]
>>> A == C
True
>>> id(A) == id(C)
False
```